# if condition on click command in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to use if condition on `element.click()` ,
could any one please help me? 
There are two different xpaths, if user click 1st xpath that is not present then click on the 2nd element

```
try{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xoath("//*[@id='vehicleNum']"));
    if(element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()){
       element.click(); // here i want if  element.click(); command 
     }
}catch(Exception e){
     WebElement element_1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='service_auto"));
     if(element_1.isDisplayed() && element_1.isEnabled()){
            element_1.sendKeys("admin");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Selenium is used to simulate user behavior by automation. what do you mean "if user click 1st xpath".

Comment: its drop down list so there  are so many list is there how to code random select?

Comment: can you add your HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

```
 try{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xoath("//*[@id='vehicleNum']"));
    if(isDisplayed(element) && isEnabled(element)){
        element.click(); // here i want if  element.click(); command 
    }
   element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='service_auto"));
   if(isDisplayed(element) && isEnabled(element)){
        element.click(); // here i want if  element.click(); command 
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }


public boolean isDispalyed(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean isEnabled(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isEnabled();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```